# Terraform. Finding combinations for for_each when one of value should be got to know

Tags: terraform

I would like to create a droplet with each of the provided regions from the already present image (snapshot). But it needs to find out the image ID in each of the regions.

I don't know how to find combinations for `for_each` when one of the values needs to get to be known.

```hcl
locals {
  regions = toset([
    "tor1",
    "sgp1",
    "sfo3",
    "lon1",
    "fra1",
    "blr1",
    "ams3",
    "nyc1",
    "nyc3",
  ])
}
```

Getting image ID in a region

```hcl
data "digitalocean_droplet_snapshot" "web-snapshot" {
  for_each    = local.regions
  name_regex  = "^s-sites"
  region      = each.key
  most_recent = true
}
```

This code doesn't work.
Creates droplet in a region with image IDs in these regions.

```hcl
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "stop-sites" {
  for_each   = local.regions
  name       = "${var.server_name}-${each.key}"
  image      = 102913678 # we should find the ID of image
  region     = each.key
  size       = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  ipv6       = true
  backups    = false
  monitoring = true
  droplet_agent = true
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: The `image` should be `data.digitalocean_droplet_snapshot.web-snapshot[each.key].id`. I think.

Comment: @Marcin `image      = 102913678` - might be another in each of the regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `data` source is using `for_each` as well, that means there will be a `data` source for each of the regions defined in the local variable (`regions`), i.e.,:

```
data.digitalocean_droplet_snapshot.web-snapshot["tor1"]
data.digitalocean_droplet_snapshot.web-snapshot["sgp1"]
...
```

In order to access the attribute for image ID which gets exported when using the `data` source, the following change needs to be done:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "stop-sites" {
  for_each   = local.regions
  name       = "${var.server_name}-${each.key}"
  image      = data.digitalocean_droplet_snapshot.web-snapshot[each.key].id
  region     = each.key
  size       = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  ipv6       = true
  backups    = false
  monitoring = true
  droplet_agent = true
}
```

One thing to note: in the case of a variable of type `set`, `each.key` and `each.value` are the same [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-each-object